# Java spring boot starter-thymeleaf - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am a beginner in springboot. I'm trying to use thymeleaf and html to display the text on localhost8080. After trying to download dependencies in maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get this message:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot: spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf: jar: 1.5.10.RELEASE

in the folder:

> "C: \ Users \ myUser \ .m2 \ repository \ org \ Spring Framework \ boot \ spring-boot-primer-thymeleaf \ 1.5.10.RELEASE"

there is a file:

> spring-boot-primer-thymeleaf-1.5.10.RELEASE.pom.lastUpdated

with the content:

> ## NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice. #Sat Mar 03 08:48:15 CET 2018 @default-central- ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1520063295482 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:pom:1.5.10.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

other dependencies such as spring-boot-starter-web or guava work correctly. Problem is the same for 2.0.0.REALESE and others. I will be grateful for any advice.

and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>AKBootCamp8</groupId>
<artifactId>kwejk</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent should be:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

And dependency should be:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Remove `<version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>` from dependency and check.

Comment: Show us your pom.xml and what version of java u are dealing with?

Comment: i added my pom.xml file above and i am dealing with Java 8

Comment: If you're using STS, go ahead and create a new spring starter project, if you use any other IDE, go ahead download demo project from spring initializr and import into your workspace as maven project. The reason why I'm saying this because I dont see any error in my workspace with the pom.xml you provided. The error "Could not transfer artifact" mostly because of network issues. Let me know once you tried it.

Comment: And use this pom.xml (from a working demo of mine): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rahul-raj/SpringBoot/master/demo/pom.xml, just remove dependencies that you dont require. If you still facing issues, thats because of your network, you may need to add proxies or setup different maven central.

Comment: thank you for the answer but nothing works. Isn't it connected with certification? previously I had a problem with maven at all and i had to add maven certificate to trust store.