# Adding spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf manually

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I manually add spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf to my Java project?
I'm trying to do it with dependencies in Maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but it does not work for me so I can not use the thymeleaf option.
I deal with Java 8. 
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: `but it does not work for me` by how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java spring boot starter-thymeleaf - unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083130/java-spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to)

Answer (score 1):

In my spring boot project I am using 1.5.3.RELEASE which is working

You can remove version tag from thymeleaf dependency
and add version in Parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I tried it and it doesn't work. I described the whole problem with dependencies in separete question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083130/java-spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to

this problem seems to be more complicated. For now, I urgently need to do part of the thymeleaf project so I would like to somehow add it to the project, for example manually.